# unserialize in ci is not working

Tags: php, serialization

I have a following problem in data-table when i run the unserialize code

Message: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset
 0 of 2 bytes

I create in controller
 $data['dep_id']   = serialize($this->input->post('dep_id'));

in model to display unserialize my code is 
 $depid = unserialize($value->dep_id);//(inside foreach)

Comment: may be $value->dep_id is empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$depid = unserialize($value['dep_id']);
```

you are mixing array and object property access